# How to save value of dynamically created HtmlInputText component

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

This question is actually the next step of question stated here:

[How to bind value of dynamically created HtmlInputText component to bean property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787053/how-to-bind-value-of-dynamically-created-htmlinputtext-component-to-bean-propert)

So the next step is to actually save the values that the user submits using the dynamic form generated in previous question (a jsf form programmatically created, consisting of simple inputexts). 
Here is the code for each component:

The model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "imageviewer_crreviewerformdata")
public class CRReviewerFormData implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "FdId")
private Long fdId;

@Column(name = "Input1")
private String input1;

@Column(name = "Input2")
private String input2;

@Column(name = "Input3")
private String input3;

/* getters & setters*/
// ...
```

The view:

```
<p:commandButton value="View" action="#{reviewReportBean.updateDynamicPanelGrid()}"
                   oncomplete="dlg.show()" icon="ui-icon-image" >
    <f:param name="selectedImage" value="#{cRImageData.imName}" />
</p:commandButton>
...
<p:outputPanel id="outerContainerDynamicPanelGrid" autoUpdate="true">
    <h:panelGrid id="innerContainerDynamicPanelGrid"
                    binding="#{reviewReportBean.dynamicPanelGrid}">
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
<p:commandButton id="viewSaveForm" value="Save" 
                    action='#{reviewReportBean.saveReport()}'>
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton id="viewEditForm" value="Edit" 
                    action='#{reviewReportBean.editReport()}'>
</p:commandButton>
...
```

The controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "reviewReportBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ReviewReportBean implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String imageOfInterest;
    private HtmlPanelGrid dynamicPanelGrid;
    private CRReviewerFormData cRReviewerFromData;
    // ...
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){     
        dynamicPanelGrid = new HtmlPanelGrid();
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ConfigOptionsBean configOptionsBean = (ConfigOptionsBean) facesContext.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(facesContext, "configOptionsBean");

        cRReviewerFromData = new CRReviewerFormData();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void updateDynamicPanelGrid() {

        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
        dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().clear();

        Row row1 = (Row) application.createComponent(Row.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        row1.setRendered(true);
        Row row2 = (Row) application.createComponent(Row.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        row2.setRendered(true);     
        Row row3 = (Row) application.createComponent(Row.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        row3.setRendered(true);

        HtmlOutputLabel label1 = (HtmlOutputLabel)application.createComponent(HtmlOutputLabel.COMPONENT_TYPE);      
        label1.setValue("I am the first label");
        label1.setStyle("font-weight:bold;color:black");
        label1.setId("label1");     
        HtmlOutputLabel label2 = (HtmlOutputLabel)application.createComponent(HtmlOutputLabel.COMPONENT_TYPE);      
        label2.setValue("I am the second label");
        label2.setStyle("font-weight:bold;color:red");
        label2.setId("label2");     
        HtmlOutputLabel label3 = (HtmlOutputLabel)application.createComponent(HtmlOutputLabel.COMPONENT_TYPE);      
        label3.setValue("I am the third label");
        label3.setStyle("font-weight:bold;color:red");
        label3.setId("label3");

        HtmlInputText input1 = (HtmlInputText)application.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        input1.setId("input1"); 
        input1.setValueExpression("value", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getELContext(), "#{reviewReportBean.input1}" , String.class));

        HtmlInputText input2 = (HtmlInputText)application.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);        
        input2.setId("input2");
        input2.setValueExpression("value", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getELContext(), "#{reviewReportBean.input2}" , String.class));

        HtmlInputText input3 = (HtmlInputText)application.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        input3.setId("input3");
        input3.setValueBinding(arg0, arg1);
        input3.setValueExpression("value", FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getELContext(), "#{reviewReportBean.input3}" , String.class));

        dynamicPanelGrid.setColumns(2);

        dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().add(label1);
        dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().add(input1);     
        dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().add(label2);
        dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().add(input2);     
        dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().add(label3);
        dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren().add(input3);
        requestContext.update(":viewDatagridForm:innerContainerDynamicPanelGrid");
    }
    // ...
}
```

How can I SAVE the value of dynamically created `HtmlInputText` components to bean properties?

I have implemented a typical Save() method in the Controller (reviewReportBean) like this:

```
public String saveReport() {
    String result = null;
    System.out.println(">>>> method to save form called!");

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    CRReviewerFormData cRReviewerFormData = new CRReviewerFormData();
    cRReviewerFormData.setInput1(this.getInput1());
    cRReviewerFormData.setInput2(this.getInput2());
    cRReviewerFormData.setInput3(this.getInput3());

    Transaction tx = null;
    try 
    {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         session.save(cRReviewerFormData);
         tx.commit();
         result = SUCCESS;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
         if (tx != null) 
         {
             tx.rollback();
             result = ERROR;
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     } 
     finally 
     {
         session.close();
     }
     return result;
}
```

When i try to use Save button i receive the following error:

```
16:44:08,632 ERROR [ExceptionHandlerAjaxImpl:57] Component ID A3702:imageEditor:label1 has already been found in the view.  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID A3702:imageEditor:label1 has already been found in the view.  
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:821)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:144)
```

and a little further down i get:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ImageViewer Servlet threw exception
javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
```

Is there any actual problem with form ids?

Is the Save method implementation i have implemented enough or do i have to set anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The problem causing the exeptions related with duplicate ids & cdata tags was solved by setting:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setTransient(true);
```

in updateDynamicPanelGrid() method